# When Go to Previous Page using href two pages merge in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am using ionic for phonegap to build mobile app.
As i have written all code and now when I click back button to returns, some times shows like below attached image.

[image]

I have used href="#/pagename" to change page in html.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Muhsin its simple <a href="#/pagename"></a>

Comment: i have faced same issue

Comment: @Muhsin What was the issue and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long Research I found the solution.Below is the refresh link and the solution.

http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

:)